# Copy file with text replacement

Tags: c++, file, search, stream, c++98

I am currently learning C++. I coded a tiny program for school and I wonder if there could be issues (like bugs or security issues) with it.
Any ways to make it have weird behaviours would be very appreciated, any suggestions to improve my code in terms or performance or readability are also welcomed.

### Instructions

> Given a file named `filename`, and two strings `s1`and `s2`, this program should create a new file named
> `filename.replace` in which all occurrences of `s1` are
> replaced by `s2`.

- code needs to compile with the `-std=c++98` flag (so no C++11 standard or more)
- I only can use the standard library's functions
- no `*printf`, `*alloc`or `free`
- no C file manipulation functions, only C++
- no `STL`, no containers nor `<algorithm>` header
- no `std::string::replace` function

---

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main( int ac, char **av )
{
    if (ac != 4) {
        std::cout << "Invalid number of arguments" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::string     infile_name(av[1]);
    std::fstream    infile(infile_name, std::ios::in);
    if (!infile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "'" << av[1]
        << "': issue while opening the file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "'" << av[1]
        << "': successfully opened in read mode" << std::endl;

    std::string     outfile_name(av[1]);
    outfile_name += ".replace";
    std::fstream    outfile(outfile_name, std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
    if (!outfile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "'" << av[1]
        << "': issue while opening the file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "'" << outfile_name
        << "': successfully opened and truncated in write mode" << std::endl;

    std::string line;
    std::string s1(av[2]);
    std::string s2(av[3]);
    size_t      pos;
    while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
        if (!infile.eof())
            line += '\n';
        do {
            pos = line.find(s1);
            if (pos == std::string::npos)
                outfile << line;
            else {
                outfile << line.substr(0, pos);
                outfile << s2;
                line = line.substr(pos + s1.size());
            }
        } while (pos != std::string::npos);
    }
    // not necessary to close the files manually as std::fstream objects are RAII
    // objects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802494/do-i-need-to-close-a-stdfstream
    // infile.close();
    // outfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the first string cannot span two lines, i.e. contain a newline?

Comment: C++98 is a pretty weird restriction these days, and really inhibits what you'll learn.  Not your fault of course, but still disappointing.

Comment: @Davislor there are no other constraints than the ones i mentioned in the post so no

Comment: @TobySpeight I agree in principle, but they are allowed to use `std::string`, which is sufficient for this. Perhaps the prof will have them coding their own implementations of the data structures shortly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `std::getline` and `std::string` are in the `<string>` header, so we need to include that.
- Rather than using `std::fstream` directly, we can use the specific types `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` for input and output files respectively.
- Error messages should be sent to `std::cerr`, rather than `std::cout`. Progress messages should go to `std::clog`. (It may not matter here, but it's a useful habit to get into for writing programs where the standard output is piped to a file, or used as input by another program.)
- We create the variable `infile_name`, but continue to use `av[1]` in many places. We should use `infile_name` throughout, since it's more meaningful.

  Note that the error message if we fail to open `outfile` shows the wrong file name. (We might have noticed if we had used the more meaningful name, instead of `av[1]` ;) ).
- Variables should be marked `const` when we don't need them to be mutable (e.g. `infile_name`, `outfile_name`, `s1`, `s2`).
- After each replacement, the line string is reassigned to a new string object: `line = line.substr(pos + s1.size());`. This is likely to be quite slow (as it will probably involve memory allocation).

  Note that `std::string::find` takes a second argument, which is the offset in the string at which to start searching. By using a second `std::size_t` variable to track the start point of the search (and adjusting the output code a bit), we can avoid the expensive substring operation.

  In modern C++, we could avoid the use of `substr` when outputting to the stream by using `std::string_view`, but that's not available in C++98.
- The code that does the actual processing could be moved to separate function:

  `void stream_replace(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out, std::string const& search_term, std::string const& replacement);`

  This is neater - it gives this section of code clear inputs and outputs, and a meaningful name, and makes our `main` function shorter and more readable.

  It also makes the code more testable: we can pass file streams to this function, but we could also pass `std::stringstream`s. So we could write a bunch of test cases with various input strings, and check that the code gives the expected output in each case. This is called unit testing.
- (Note that both `std::string` and the file streams are in the C++ standard library (often and somewhat erroneously called the STL - see the [big purple box at the bottom of this page for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/cpp-standard-library-overview?view=msvc-170)). `std::string` is definitely a container type. This may just be just a mistake in the instructions you've been given; if you're sure you can use `std::string` then I don't think you're doing anything wrong. If you're actually supposed to avoid `std::string` too, then you'll probably need to look into using a fixed size character array when processing the files.)

Comment: If the prof means [the literal Standard Template Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library), it does not include `std::string`, which was separate—or, interestingly, any of the hash tables, such as `std::unordered_map`, which were added later.

Comment: I suspect she actually meant, “Any standard library container other than `std::string`,” but if I were giving an assignment like this, I would probably list the headers whose interfaces students are allowed to use.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the excellent review by [user673679](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/284016/271531). I am writing this review as ignoring the assignment constraints. Places where I violate the constraints are marked with **[NA]**

1. Don't change names of common variables a.k.a `argv`, `argc`. Everyone recognises these variables.
2. Don't do unnecessary indentations. There is no need to align variable names with spurious spaces.
3. Prefer `auto var = Type(arg);` over `Type var(arg)`. In the second version, it is easy to get into [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) problem, if the constructor for `Type` does not take any parameters. Or outright forget the braces and have a uninitialized type.
4. Never use command-line arguments aka `argv` throug out the code. Instead validate the arguments as early as possible and package them into proper types.
5. **[NA]** Prefer `std::string_view` over `std::string` or `const char * const`

## Weird edge case

Your method fails if `s1` is a multiline string.

Comment: Regarding 3., the C++ Core Guidelines even prefers `Type var{args}` [ES.23](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-list).

Comment: The core guidelines talks about `{}` vs `()` not `auto var = Type(arg)` vs `Type var(arg)`. The core guideline prefers braced initialisation `{}` over calling the constructor `()` to avoid narrowing conversions. In 3, I am arguing for what the community calls 'Almost Always Auto'. These are two seperate ideas. Almost always auto makes your code uniform and makes it harder to not initialize a variable and has nothing to do with narrowing conversions.